# Why did Rabbi Akiva give smichah to the 5 talmidim if Rabbi Yehudah ben Bova already gave them?

Tags: semicha

Why did they receive semicha twice?
They both gave semicha to Rabbi Meir, Rabbi Yehudah, Rabbi Shimon, Rabbi Yehudah bar Iloiy, Rabbi Elozor ben Shamua.
I noticed Rabbi Yehudah ben Bova also gave Rav Ivah and Rav Nechemya.
Maseches yevomus 62b
Maseches sanhedrin 14a

Comment: Also interning "אמר רבי יוחנן: סתם מתניתין - רבי מאיר, סתם תוספתא - רבי נחמיה, סתם ספרא - רבי יהודה, סתם ספרי - רבי שמעון, וכולהו אליבא דרבי עקיבא." also interesting that rebbi akiva the second round  is counted as being rabbi nechemia source. Sanhedrin 86a

Comment: It says Rabbi Akiva taught them. It doesn't say he gave them semicha

Comment: It says here -ובמורה באצבע לחיד"א (סימן ח' אות רכ"ג) כתב: יום ל"ג לעומר ירבה בשמחה לכבוד רשב"י זיע"א, כי הוא יומא דהלולא דיליה. ונודע שרצונו הוא שישמחו ביום זה... עכ"ל החיד"א. והביא דבריו בכף החיים (תצ"ג ס"ק כ"ו) והביא גם דעת הבני יששכר שהובא לעיל. [עוד הביא עפ"י שער הכוונות שהשמחה היא על כך שרבי עקיבא סמך את חמשת תלמידיו, ובלשונו: ולכן סמך אח"כ רבי עקיבא את חמשת תלמידיו הגדולים...ואלו נתקיימו בעולם והרביצו תורה ברבים... ובסיום דבריו כתב: ואפשר דהא והא איתא...עכ"ל כף החיים. -

Comment: It's mashma above - https://www.hidush.co.il/hidush.asp?id=22822 - in shaar hakavonos of the ari and achronim mentioned that rabbi akiva gave semicha on lag beomer

Comment: @yosefkorn If your question is premised on a somewhat obscure source, that should be included in the question post.

Comment: I think Rabbi Akiva gave semicha first.   Rabbi Yehuda Ben Baba was the last of the 10 to be killed by Romans.